# Magento Admin not referencing any JS or CSS

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

Magento 1.6.2
Dedicated Server

This morning I installed Fooman Speedster, everything turned to back immediately. Uninstalling it did no seem to undo the destruction.

Following a lot of posts, I have cleared all cache files and checked file/folder permissions.

Currently, I have got the frontend is functioning properly and orders are being placed.

The problem left is with the CMS. No CSS or JS files are being called.

Therefore, no buttons within the admin are working and nothing can be done from within there.

CSS is there on the admin login and MagentoConnect parts. But the main admin part is not working.

Any ideas on how to get the admin calling CSS and JS again?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this compress and combines all css and js . Have you taken any backup? Have u installed it from mage connect ?

Comment: Yep, installed from connect, uninstalled and reinstalled from there too.

Comment: if still not working then please /var/cache folder and look in var/log/ecxeption.log and system.log for system.log